# Keep in touch with a company located in another country

Tags: internship, international

I am just about to complete an one year exchange student program (in Canada if it matters) that included a internship of 3 months in a private company.

I like this company a lot, and on my last week of work they said that they have interest in hiring me as a full time employee, and thus are *extending the internship invitation*.

The thing is that I am not from Canada and I **have** to go back to my country and finish my graduation there. So far I've completed one year and a half out of a 5 years program.

My boss here knows that I need to return and also that there is a looooong way to go before I finish my program (3.5 years, to be exact).

If the company were located on the same country as my university, I would simply ask for another internship in the next summer. However this is kinda hard for me since it would be really expensive to move to Canada for a couple months (find a house, pay the airplane tickets, get basic furniture...).

I am afraid they won't have more interest in me after 3.5 years or something similar (*like my boss quitting the company and the new boss not knowing me*).

**What can i do in order to hold this job opportunity?**

Note: We don't use Linkedin and although I have a good personal relationship with them I am far from having them on my social networks (Facebook, Twitter and etc...).

If you need any extra info about this, feel free to ask. :)

I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: `We don't use Linkedin` Why?

Comment: Some of us don't like social media.

Comment: @Lilienthal Well... I don't know why, but they don't. You can find 4 or 5 profiles there, but I believe most of them were created before working for the company. Also it isn't really common to use Linkedin in my home country too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**There must be perfection in the timing, not just the role**

While it is very difficult at this point to let go of what seems like a perfect opportunity, it's clear that there are enough circumstances around it that it actually is *not* something that you could practicably do at this stage of your life and with your remaining study.

Rather than focus on this *one* opportunity, instead concentrate of finalising your studies and exploring other possibilities.  You may find that the next place you go may fit you even better and may not have the same issues you currently face.

By all means, look for any ways around your current issue but sometimes you have to let go of something that just cannot happen so you can move forward with the *right* opportunity, both in fit and timing :)

Keep in touch with this employer.  If there is still an opportunity with the organisation when you are finished your degree and everything else has settled in your life, grab it with both hands.  But if you dwell on it too much now, you might just overlook the better one :)

Comment: I was thinking only about grabbing this opportunity and not letting it go. I never really stopped to think that maybe this isn't the right thing for me right now. *I loved the environment of my work place, the happy atmosphere that we have here and what I had to do here.* That is why is so hard to simply let it go. I will be open for new opportunities but surely try to come here after my 3+ years of studies. I honestly appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you think you have a good relationship with your boss (but not necessarily with your company), then keep in touch with the boss.

> Well thank you: very much. I wish you could ask me that later, because I have to go back to school now, as you know, and I won't graduate for another 3 years; but I'd love the opportunity to work with you again. How can I stay in touch with you over the next 3 years, and contact you again when I graduate?

Then maybe they'll volunteer or you can ask for their personal email address; and/or make friends with their LinkedIn profile.

> We don't use Linkedin and ... Facebook, Twitter and etc...

Well, if they don't do personal email either, ask for their *mailing* address at home: say that it's "so that I can send you a Christmas card!"

---

And/or if you're more interested in the company than the boss, ask if you could have a meeting with more than one person (e.g. your boss *and* their boss, or your boss *and* an HR person): to discuss your future with the company. By doing that you would have a second contact (in case your current boss leaves) within the company, who knows (based on the meeting) that the company wants you.